# AngularJS directive will only work until ng-include changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some AngularJS directives that will only work once. When the view changes and you return they no longer work, there is no page refresh involved, but we use a simple view loading system using ng-include for the page changes (Sub pages not main routes).

I have some markup that is something like this.

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <ul class="sidebar span3" sub-nav>
        <li><a ng-click="changePage('users')">Users</a></li>
        <li><a ng-click="changePage('posts')">Posts</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="span9" view-partial ng-include="route[active]"></div>
</div>
```

the "sub-nav" directive has a method to update the "active" scope variable. I then have a directive that listens for changes to the "active" variable and emits a "pageChange" event if the value is different. (They are separate from the controller as they are applied to more than just one). There is only one controller running this code at a time and it seems to work perfectly.

Inside the ng-include we are using ng-repeat to loop over the data, in the table this loop produces we have a delete button with a directive applied to it just like this one

```
angular.module("myModule")

    .directive("deleteBtn", function(delConf) {
        require: "?ngModel",
        link: function(scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {
            elm.bind("click", function(e) {
                // here i open a modal window and pass some data to it
                // just as a delete confirmation the logic for it is tucked 
                // away in delConf
            }
        }
    })

    .directive("deleteConfBtn", function(delConf) {
        require: "?ngModel",
        link: function(scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {
            elm.bind("click", function(e) {
                // here i make the api request to delete the item and remove it
                // from the scope
            }
        }            
    });
```

The first directive is applied to the delete button in the table (This one will always work, even when the view changes). The second directive is applied to a button on a bootstrap modal window.

The second directive will only work after a page refresh. I think its to do with scope but I can't figure out why one works and the other fails.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you create a Plunker with your code?

Comment: hmm seems to work ok in this http://plnkr.co/edit/Nj8thsl6vsSwLy3rqGhB

Comment: Maybe the issue is elsewhere, even though that code is simplified, there is not allot more to that functionality, but there is much more stuff going on around it